# How can I improve performance of this function?

Tags: algorithm, performance, haskell, recursion, optimization

I'm trying to implement a seam carving algorithm in Haskell. I'm using the [JuicyPixels](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels)-package for this.

I think I'm almost done, but the following function is rendering the performance unbearable. `+RTS -p -RTS` profiling tells me it's responsible for `98 %time` and `99 %alloc` of the whole program.
This is it:

```
f :: Image Pixel8 -> Int -> Int -> (Int,(Int,Int))
f img 0 r = (fromIntegral (pixelAt img 0 r),(r,0))
f img@(Image {..}) c r = maximumBy (comparing fst) [ ( (fst (f img (c-1) (r+j) )) + (fromIntegral (pixelAt img c r)) , (r+j,c-1) ) | j<-js ]
    where js | r==0 = [0,1]
             | r==(imageHeight-1) = [-1,0]
             | otherwise = [-1,0,1]
```

Some info:

- f is given an image `img` (which is basically a vector of unboxed `Word8`s indexed by rows and columns. elements can be accessed by `pixelAt`) and pixel coordinates `c`,`r`, which determine the starting pixel.
- f looks for the highest sum of pixel values among horizontal contours to the left of (r,c) (direction `c-1`), i.e. connected lines of pixels which may differ in row coordinate by no more than `1` (the definition of `js` in the where clause captures this).
- To do this, f recursively looks for the highest such sums in all left-connected pixels.
- f should output `(val,(r',c'))`, where `val` is the maximal contour sum it has found and `(r',c')` are the coordinates of the next pixel in this contour after `(r,c)`.
- So, complexity is pretty much a function of `c` right now, since the further right the starting column (higher `c`), the more recursive steps to the left will have to be computed until the image boundary (base case, `c=0`) is reached.

Some time data on my machine:

```
c=15 : 2.544s
c=16 : 7.025s
c=17 : 20.482s
```

Anything above 17 I had to kill so far.

I'd be very grateful if anyone could point out some performance improvements I could try here. This is my first haskell program and I'm so close!

Comment: I'd recommend you stop using lists and try to rewrite the algorithm with a manual loop or even better use a proper array library. For this particular algorithm I'd recommend to use Stencil functionality in massiv: https://github.com/lehins/massiv There is also massiv-io package that can help you interface with JuicyPixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examining your code, it looks like you're computing some values more than once.  Specifically, each time you subtract `1` from `c`, you're passing a range of values for `r`, and as you subtract more, the range increases.  Furthermore, not only does it look like many of these `r` values overlap, but each of these calls will recur themselves.  In short, you're recomputing a lot of results that you've already found.

This seems like a pretty classic case of [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), and you should be able to get a good performance boost by [memoizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) your function.  There are various libraries for memoization in Haskell, and I'm not sure which one's best, but any of them should reduce the complexity of your calculation, which means that any of them should give you a big performance upgrade.

One memoization tool that could help is [memo-trie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie-0.6.10/docs/Data-MemoTrie.html), which should be pretty easy to use.  The following code should do the trick for you:

```hs
import Data.MemoTrie (memo2)

f :: Image Pixel8 -> Int -> Int -> (Int,(Int,Int))
f img@(Image {..}) = f'
  where
    f' = memo2 go
    go 0 r = fromIntegral (pixelAt img 0 r),(r,0) 
    go c r = maximumBy (comparing fst) [ ( (fst (f' (c-1) (r+j) )) + (fromIntegral (pixelAt img c r)) , (r+j,c-1) ) | j<-js ]
      where js | r==0 = [0,1]
               | r==(imageHeight-1) = [-1,0]
               | otherwise = [-1,0,1]
```

Comment: Yes! This is precisely what was missing. Using your suggestion has improved time for `c=17` down to `0.308s` from `>20s`. Thank you so much for it and the explanation! =)